# Dialog element 'open' event

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, modal-dialog, html-5.2

For the dialog element `<dialog>`, is there some sort of "open" event that is fired when it is shown, either normally or as a modal?

[The spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element) isn't totally clear on this, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement) just lists a bunch of inherited events.

The `close` event *does* fire, but I can't seem to get any sort of `open` event.

Example HTML:

```
<dialog>
  <h1>Oh hey, a dialog...</h1>
</dialog>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('dialog').addEventListener('open', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();
```

Comment: Just a guess try `show` event?

Comment: @Viney Unfortunately, that event doesn't fire either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no `open` event.

The dialog has an `open` property which can determine if it's opened or not, but unfortunately there's no event when this transitions.

Comment: There is currently no other way to open it than through javascript ( [related issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3567) ), so it makes sense there is no event being sent here. However as you noted, the `open` property changes, but what you didn't say is that this IDL attribute reflects an HTML attribute, which is observable: https://jsfiddle.net/vmj8d79q/ Also, I think there should be a `focus` event to fire, but no current implementations seem to do that, and I may just have misread the specs.

Comment: @Kaiido Your MutationObserver method is a good workaround!  Please post as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks, as always.  :-)

Comment: @Brad I brought here this missing answer with the use of the MutationObserver(). I improved it by making it global and protected in an IIFE

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution to your problem would be this :

```html
<dialog id="dial">
  <h3> dialog element </h3>
  <button id="close">x</button>
</dialog>
<button id="buttonDialog" > Open   </button>
<button id="buttonDialog2"> Open 2 </button>
```

```js
const
  dialog  = document.getElementById('dial')
, close   = document.getElementById('close')
, button  = document.getElementById('buttonDialog')
, button2 = document.getElementById('buttonDialog2')
  ;
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  dialog.showModal()
  })
close.addEventListener('click', event => {
  dialog.close()
  })
let observer = new MutationObserver(function()  {
  if (event[0].attributeName == 'open') console.log('updated')
  });
observer.observe(dialog, { attributes: true })
  ;
button2.addEventListener('click', event => {
  dialog.setAttribute('open', true)
  })
```

Comment: Yes, duck punching/monkey patching can work.  Though I worry about situations where the dialog is opened/closed by other means.  I think dialogs can be opened with anchor fragments, can't they?  Or did that part of the spec never land?

Comment: Hice el mismo codigo capturando la mutación del objeto, es mas general y podes usarlo como evento de cualquier propiedad

Comment: All posts are expected to be in English. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: I edited the same code, it captures the mutation of the object, it is more general and you can use it as an event of any property

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments/anwers here, it is possible to generate this event using a [MutationObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

As the answers here seem cruelly incomplete (even wrong), I did my own experiments to compose an easily exploitable answer.

Nota :
_ `<dialog>` JS objects always have an `open` **property**, and it is a boolean value (true or false), even if this **attribute** is not present on the HTML declaration.

1st solution :

```js
(() =>  // IIFE => add  event 'dialog-open' to all Dialog elements
  {
  const
    OpenEvent = new CustomEvent('dialog-open') 
  , ObserverM = new MutationObserver( recs =>
    {
    recs.forEach( ({attributeName: attr, target: dial }) =>
      {
      if (attr === 'open' && dial.open )
        dial.dispatchEvent( OpenEvent );    
      })
    });
  document.querySelectorAll('dialog').forEach( dial =>
    {
    ObserverM.observe( dial, { attributes: true } );
    })
  })() // IIFE end...

const
  btShowDial = document.querySelector('#bt-show_mDialog')
, dialogBox  = document.querySelector('#dialog-box')
, dialBForm  = document.querySelector('#dialog-box form')
  ;
btShowDial.onclick =_=>
  {
  dialogBox.showModal()
  }
dialogBox.addEventListener('dialog-open', () =>
  {
  dialBForm.inNum.valueAsNumber =  0 | Math.random() *10**4
  dialogBox.returnValue = 'exit with Escape key'
  })
dialogBox.onclose=_=>
  {
  console.log(`${dialBForm.inNum.value } is ${dialogBox.returnValue}` )
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-show_mDialog">show modal dialog..</button>

<dialog id="dialog-box">
  <form method="dialog">
    <h3>Dialog -1-</h3>
    <label> mumeric : <input type="number" name="inNum"></label>
    <br>
    <button value="good"> good </button>
    <button value="bad" > bad </button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Personally, I prefer to use their event methods directly on DOM Objects.
They have the advantage of being unique, and of making the code more readable.
so might as well add this one, rather than creating a specific custom event!

2nd solution :

```js
(() =>  // IIFE => add  event 'dialog-open' to all Dialog elements
  {
  const Dialogs = document.querySelectorAll('dialog');

  Dialogs.forEach( dial => dial.onOpen = function(){} )  // add onOpen empty method.

  const ObserverM = new MutationObserver( recs =>
    {
    recs.forEach( ({attributeName: attr, target: dial }) =>
      {
      if (attr === 'open' && dial.open ) dial.onOpen();  // call onOpen Method...  
      })
    });
  Dialogs.forEach( dial => ObserverM.observe( dial, { attributes: true }))
  })() // IIFE end...

const
  btShowDial = document.querySelector('#bt-show_mDialog')
, dialogBox  = document.querySelector('#dialog-box')
, dialBForm  = document.querySelector('#dialog-box form')
  ;
btShowDial.onclick =_=>
  {
  dialogBox.showModal()
  }
dialogBox.onOpen =_=>
  {
  dialBForm.inNum.valueAsNumber =  0 | Math.random() *10**4
  dialogBox.returnValue         = 'exit with Escape key'
  }
dialogBox.onclose=_=>
  {
  console.log(`${dialBForm.inNum.value } is ${dialogBox.returnValue}` )
  }
```

```css
dialog::backdrop {
  background: #00ddff5d;
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-show_mDialog">show modal dialog..</button>

<dialog id="dialog-box">
  <form method="dialog">
    <h3>Dialog -1-</h3>
    <label> mumeric : <input type="number" name="inNum"></label>
    <br>
    <button value="good"> good </button>
    <button value="bad" > bad </button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```